# Developer story - "Honors & Awards" section

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

Is it possible to create an additional section "Honors & Awards" in the developer story? I've found only the section "Certifications" more or less suitable for such purposes, but it's confusing.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [Add an honors & awards section](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/161057)